# Pedir dato al usuario

Tags: r

Quiero hacer un autoejecutable .BAT  de unos datos que comparan fechas:

```
    datos <- read.table(text = '
    fecha edad
    01/05/2020  20
    02/01/2019  33
    03/05/2017  19
    04/05/2018  3
    09/05/2020  25
    ', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   datos$fecha <- as.Date(datos$fecha, format="%d/%m/%Y") 
    
fecha_referencia <- as.Date("25/11/2019", format="%d/%m/%Y")
    
datos$fecha < fecha_referencia
```

La fecha_referencia puede cambiar. Tendría que editar el archivo dependiendo de la fecha antes de ejecutar el archivo.

¿Existe la forma de que al ejecutar el archivo este le pida al usuario la fecha mediante un mensaje en pantalla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R tiene sus particularidades a la hora de procesar el ingreso por teclado, hay un comportamiento cuando el script se ejecuta interactivamente, desde el ide de R o Rstudio y otro cuando se automatiza en una llamada por línea de comando.

Por ejemplo, para pedir una fecha y de paso validar que pueda realmente transformarse en una fecha, podrías implementar algo así:

```
input_date <- function(prompt) {
  fecha <- NA
  while (is.na(fecha)) {
    if (interactive() ) {
      input <- readline(prompt=prompt)
    } else {
      cat(prompt);
      input <- readLines("stdin", n=1);
    }
    fecha <- as.Date(input, format="%d/%m/%Y")
  }
  fecha
}

fecha_referencia <- input_date("Ingrese una fecha en formato dd/mm/yyyy:")
cat(paste("Fecha ingresada:", fecha_referencia))
```

Como puedes observar se usan funciones distintas según como se invoque el Script, `readline()` en el IDE y `readLines()` desde la línea de comandos . Para probarlo, considera:

1. Desde Rstudio, deberás hacer un click en el botón `source`
2. Desde un script y llamándolo por línea de comandos: `Rscript.exe script.r`

Answer (score 1):

Claro, puedes preguntar:

```
set /p fecha=Qué fecha referencia necesitas? (Ejemplo:10\07\2022)?:
echo %fecha%
```

Luego de eso tendrás disponible una variable %fecha% que tendrás que validar para asegurarte que el usuario ponga datos correctos.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción sería utilizar `readline` dentro del script:

```
fecha_referencia <- readline(prompt = "Favor ingresar fecha en formato dia/mes/año.")
```

Puedes establecer un test para asegurarte que ingresen bien la fecha:

```
prueba = vector()

while(length(prueba)==0){
  fecha_referencia <- readline(prompt = "Favor ingresar fecha en formato dia/mes/año: ")
  prueba <- grep(pattern = '[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/2[0-9][0-9][0-9]',x = fecha_referencia)  
  if(length(prueba)>0){
    cat('Gracias\n')
  }
  else{
    cat('Favor intentar nuevamente\n')
  }
}
```

Comment: si ejecuto el código desde rstudio va bien, si lo ejecuto desde una terminal en linux con Rscript ejemplo.R entra en bucle. Supongo que a eso se refería Patricio Moracho